# Got Missing template error when running cucumber test on Circle CI server but locally all tests are passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

On my local machine all tests are passing but on CircleCI server all test with selenium fails after the scenarios. So it seems like all steps are passing but after scenario it's looking for some template.

**Gemfile**:

```
ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem "unicorn", "~> 4.7.0"
gem "unicorn-rails", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "pg", "~> 0.17.1"
gem "heroku", "~> 3.6.0"
gem "devise", "~> 3.2.2"
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem "active_admin_importable", "~> 1.1.2"
gem "ransack", github: "activerecord-hackery/ransack"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.0.4"
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem "omniauth", "~> 1.1.4"
gem "omniauth-facebook", "~> 1.5.1"
gem "fog"
gem "browser", "~> 0.3.2"
gem "premailer-rails", "~> 1.6.1"
gem "hstore-attributes", "~> 0.0.4"
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem "uglifier", "~> 2.4.0"
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem "possessive"
gem 'draper', '~> 1.3'
gem "gravatar_image_tag", "~> 1.2.0"
gem "memcachier", "~> 0.0.2"
gem "dalli", "~> 2.7.0"

group :staging, :demo, :production do
  gem "rails_12factor", "~> 0.0.2"
end

group :development do
  gem "rack-mini-profiler"
  gem 'flatten_migrations'
end

group :development, :test, :staging, :demo do
  gem "awesome_print"
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.3.0"
  gem "faker", "~> 1.2.0"
  gem "git-smart", "~> 0.1.9"
end

group :test do
  gem "shoulda-matchers", "~> 2.5.0"
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14.0"
  gem "capybara", "~> 2.2.1"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 1.2.0"
  gem "xpath", "~> 2.0.0"
  gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.41.0"
  gem "capybara-firebug", '~> 2.0.0'
  gem "codeclimate-test-reporter", require: false
  gem "timecop", "~> 0.7.0"
  gem "cucumber-rails", "~>1.4.0", :require => false
end

gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.7.1'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'pry-debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'capybara-screenshot', :group => :test
```

**env.rb**

```
require 'factory_girl'
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'capybara/firebug'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara-screenshot/cucumber'

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.javascript_driver = :selenium
  config.run_server = true
  config.default_selector = :css
  config.default_wait_time = 10

  config.match = :prefer_exact
  config.ignore_hidden_elements = false
end
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app| 
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new 
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new( app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile ) 
end

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish        to use it."
end

Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
def wait_for_ajax
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
    active = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active')
    until active == 0
      active = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active')
    end
  end
end
```

**error**:

```
Missing template home/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb]}. Searched in:
    * "/home/ubuntu/wyzyr/app/views"
    * "/home/ubuntu/wyzyr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/active_admin_importable-1.1.2/app/views"
    * "/home/ubuntu/wyzyr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-8c2ff62c30be/app/views"
    * "/home/ubuntu/wyzyr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views"
    * "/home/ubuntu/wyzyr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views"
   (ActionView::MissingTemplate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problem might be in ruby version that is used by CircleCi. In the Gemfile: 2.1.1 but error returns ruby/2.1.0